# How to create autoencoder with pretrained encoder decoder?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I have trained and saved the encoder and decoder separately. Now I can encode some images using the encoder and then decode/reconstruct the encoded data with the decoder in two steps. How can I decode these two steps in one step? How do I concatenate encoder-decoder to make autoencoder?

```
# What I have

from tensorflow.keras import models

encoder = model.load_model('path encoder')
decoder = model.load_model('path decoder')

encoded = encoder.predict('some image data')
decoded = decoder.predict(encoder)

# what I want
from tensorflow.keras import models

encoder = model.load_model('path encoder')
decoder = model.load_model('path decoder')

autoencoder = concatenate(encoder, decoder) # dont know how to the this

autoencoder.evaluate('some image data')
```

Answer (score 0):

After building the encoder and decoder, you can use [sequential](https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/) API to build the complete auto-encoder model as follows:

```
encoder = Model(...)
decoder = Model(...)

autoencoder = keras.Sequential()
autoencoder.add(encoder)
autoencoder.add(decoder)

# check layout 
utils.plot_model(autoencoder, show_shapes=True, expand_nested=True)
```